# How to set the calendar dates unselectable accordingly to the dropdownlist users select?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i set the calendar dates unselectable accordingly to the name in the DropDownList the users select? In other words, each name in the DropDownList will have different unselectable dates set and i tried to use the following codes to execute my program but it seems to be not working. How do i do so?

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "WeddingPlanner1")
    {
        if (e.Day.Date.Month == 7 || e.Day.Date.Month == 9 || e.Day.Date.Month == 12)
    {

        if (e.Day.Date.Day == 5 || e.Day.Date.Day == 14 || e.Day.Date.Day == 18)
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            e.Cell.Font.Bold = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this in WPF or ?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/417649/How-to-set-the-calendar-dates-unselectable-accordi#answer1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a day readonly of a asp.net calendar control using the same code what you have, but in the _DayRender event

Comment: At first, i did the method that you state. But it doesnt match the condition that i wanted. In that case, whatever name the user clicks, the unselectable dates will be the same.